# Examples of The structured clone algorithm

Tags: javascript, object, clone, web-worker

I have this giant object(class) with other objects(classes) inside and so on.
I've read about [The structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm#See_also)
 and i am trying to send this object to web worker but cant find a way...
Documentation says that

> Structured clones can correctly duplicate objects containing cyclic graphs of references.

Comment: The values will be automatically structured cloned when you send them to the web worker. postMessage does it internally.

Comment: can you give me an example? It works in chrome?

Comment: What do you mean by "*I can't find a way*" - did you try something that did not work? Show us the code of your attempt, and describe how it did not work.

Comment: cannot copy object but lets say that object have many functions as methods... Return error 'An object could not be cloned'.

Comment: cannot copy object but lets say that object have many functions as methods... worker1.postMessage(obj, [obj.tbl]); Return error Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': Value at index 0 does not have a transferable type.

Comment: Functions cannot be cloned indeed, they'll be ingnored. And no, you don't want to *transfer* anything here, so don't use the second parameter (which is for blobs and buffers).